# Conditional Cut and Paste a selected row to a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following formula that searches for rows with the text 'Completed' in collumn C on 'Live and pipeline'sheet. if that condition is met, cut and paste the whole row to the 'Completed' Sheet in the same workbook. There should be no empty rows in Sheet1 after this procedure.

At the moment I am getting `Application Run time error 1004, Application defined or object defined error` on line `Selection.Cut Shift:=xlUp`. The whole code is in Module1. Can anyone tell me what's gone wrong here?

```
Sub Completed_Projects()
'
' Move completed projects to the Completed Tab
'
'   Search until an empty cell is reached
Dim Row As Integer
Row = Range("Total_Completed").Row
Dim SumRow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C8:C100").Cells
    If Cell.Value = "Completed" Or Cell.Value = "Aborted" Then
       Rows(Cell.Row).Select
       Selection.Cut Shift:=xlUp

       ' Paste Selection
       Reference = "A" & Row
       Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Completed").Range(Reference))
       Range(Reference).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
       ActiveSheet.Paste

       ' Update Counters and go back to Live sheet
       Sheets("Live and pipeline").Select
       Row = Row + 1
    End If
Next Cell
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I've cleaned your code up a bit.

```
Sub Completed_Projects()
    Dim rw As Integer, counter As Integer

    counter = Range("Total_Completed").Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For rw = 100 To 8 Step -1
            If Worksheets("Live and Pipeline").Range("C" & rw) = "Completed" Or Worksheets("Live and Pipeline").Range("C" & rw) = "Aborted" Then
                Rows(rw).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("A" & counter)
                Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next rw
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your reply. It works brilliantly except I need the function to Destination cell to be inserted not pasted (to avoid overriding the totals row). I tried changing the 'Copy' to 'Insert' and also tried adding Shift:=xlDown but neither seem to work.

Comment: I added the following line 'Worksheets("Completed").Rows(counter).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown' above the Copy line and it now works perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok great stuff. Please accept the answer if it now works fine for you.